# something TailwindCSS styles are not effective in my Next js app

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I don't know why, in my Nextjs app, there were times when I used the tailwind style to set the width and height of an element, but instead needed to create a class and then add the appropriate Settings to that class.Also, in the same element, I set the styles such as flex to work, but I never set the width and height to work (I need to manually create a class to add in this class).In addition, I also included this file in the tailwind.config.ts pair

Here's my example

```
Footer/index.tsx
export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="w100%">
      // this footer is a class I created manually
      {/* <div className="footer"> */}
        // The width and height Settings here are not in effect
      <div className="h100% py-40px mx-100px">
        // The width and height Settings here are not in effect
        <div className="h100% flex flex-row mx-100px justify-between items-center">
          <div>....</div>
          <ul>something about my social links</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

Footer/Footer.module.css

```css
footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  height: 130px;

  .footer {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0 100px;
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: ["./src/ui/**/**/*.{ts,jsx,tsx}", "./src/app/**/*.{ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {},
      colors: {},
    },
    keyframes: {},
  },
};
export default config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things that you did wrong. [It's important you visit the docs and use it as a guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)

- `w100%` is not a tailwind class. Instead, it's `w-full`
- `h100%` is not a tailwind class. Instead, it's `h-full`

When using Arbitrary values,

- `mx-100px` is supposed to be mx-[100px]
- `py-40px`  - `py-[40px]`

```
export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="w-full">
      {/* <div className="footer"> */}
      <div className="h-full py-[40px] mx-[100px]">
        <div className="h-full flex flex-row mx-[100px] justify-between items-center">
          <div>....</div>
          <ul>something about my social links</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, otherwise I would not have realized how stupid my mistake was 